# Order of function calling

Tags: c++, c

What will be the order the function calls in the following expression:

```
a = f1(23, 14) * f2(12/4) + f3();
```

Does it depend on the compiler?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Order of evaluation of each operand is **unspecified** in C and C++, which means, in your case, the order of function calling is *unspecified* as per the Standards.

Note that it is *unspecified*, **not** *implementation-defined*.

Comment: +1 for the correct usage of unspecified vs. implementation-defined which seems to cause a lot of confusion

Comment: @hroptatyr: The difference is that implementation-defined behavior must be documented by the implementation.

Comment: if the operator is `||` or `&&`, the order is fixed and the behavior is well-defined.

Answer (score 6):

It is **Unspecified** in both C and C++.

**References:**

**C++03 Standard:Section 5: Expressions, Para 4:**

> except where noted [e.g. special rules for && and ||], the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the **order in which side effects take place, is Unspecified**.

**C99 Standard:Section 6.5:**

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.72) Except as specified later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), **the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified**.

Answer (score 4):

C++ : The standard guarantees that all expressions encountered before a sequence point are evaluated before that sequence point is reached. In your case, there is no sequence point between `=` and `;`, so the order is unspecified.

Comment: Your statement is wrong, there is a sequence point before each function is called, after the parameters of that function is evaluated. See ISO 9899:2011 6.5.2.2 §10. `"There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call."`. So in the OPs case there are 3 sequence points before the `;` is reached. But nobody will be happier knowing about that, it is not related to the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

The order can't be predicted in this case. It's not compiler dependent, it's unspecified; even with same compiler you can get different orders of evaluation.

Comment: It can't be predicted based on the requirements of the language standard.  It's entirely possible that it can be predicted if you happen to know enough about how the compiler behaves (but any such prediction doesn't apply to other compilers).  It could be "compiler dependent" in the sense that it depends choices made by the compiler.

Comment: if its the same compiler it will produce same output everytime?

Comment: I believe dat one compiler should produce same results .. let me know if I am wrong

Comment: I think you must be correct, since c++ compiler doesn't use any execution time optimization. But cant be sure too as standard doesnt speak anything about the order. http://ideone.com/gHuDF#view_edit_box

Comment: @Rohit As far as the language is concerned, no; a compiler could decide the order based on a byte read from `/dev/random`. In practice, given the same code, and the same optimization options, a given version of the compiler will produce the same order.  Change the version, the optimization options, or anything in the code surrounding the call, and all bets are off.

Comment: @Hem You're wrong.  Change the level of optimization, and the compiler could easily change the order of the function calls.  Changing the arguments (using a more complicated expression, for example), and the order could change as well.

Comment: You are confusing me guys! Please come to an answer. Whether same compiler produce same output every time or not?

Comment: @Rohit: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  You said the order cannot be predicted.  You can predict it *if* you happen to be using a compiler that generates the calls in some predictable order.  A compiler may legally always generate the calls in the same order.  Or it may legally generate the calls in some literally random order, or based on the phase of the moon (that's unlikely).  The order is unspecified, meaning that the compiler can do what it likes and needn't document its decision, but they must be called in one of the 6 possible orders (123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321).

Comment: @Rohit: And if, in some restricted circumstances, it happens to be possible to predict the order, that still doesn't do you any good.  Writing code that *depends* on the order is a really bad idea.

Comment: So it cant be predicted even if run on the same compiler and machine?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just saying that this is unspecified, end of story, let me explain how this will be evaluated. Most importantly, don't mix up the concept of *order of evaluation* (of operands) with the concept of *operator precedence*, they are different things.

- The order in which the whole expression itself is evaluated is easy to understand in this case, when we only have the basic math operators. But it can be less trivial when other C operators are involved. Therefore, always start evaluating an expression by finding out what order the sub expressions will be evaluated:
- The *operator precedence* rules are guaranteed to be the same for every compiler. They state that the binary multiplication operator (*) has higher priority than the binary addition operator (+). Both of them have higher priority than the assignment operator (=). So it is guaranteed that the sub expression `f1(23, 14) * f2(12/4)` will be evaluated first, then the result of that will become an operand of the addition with `f3()` and finally the result will be assigned to `a`.
- To illustrate this, the expression is equal to `a = ( (f1(23, 14) * f2(12/4)) + f3() );`.
- So we have the sub expression `f1(23, 14) * f2(12/4)`. The *order of evaluation* in which the operands themselves are evaluated is *unspecified behavior*, meaning that we cannot know whether the f1 or the f2 operand is evaluated first. The compiler is free to evaluate them either left-to-right or right-to-left, and does not need to document which way that applies. All we know is that the compiler will consistently evaluate either left-to-right or right-to-left.
- Let us assume that the particular compiler evaluates left-to-right. `f1(23, 14)` will then be evaluated first. The next question then, is which of the parameters to the function that will be evaluated first. Same thing applies here, the order of evaluation of function parameters is also unspecified. In this case it doesn't matter, as both parameters are integer constants.
- With left-to-right order of evaluation, the compiler will evaluate (and execute) f1 first, then f2, then multiply their results and store it in a temporary, invisible variable. It will then evaluate f3, and then perform the addition and finally assign the result to `a`.

The important lesson learned here is: since the order of evaluation of sub-expressions is unspecified, each sub-expression should not contain any side effects that depends on the order of evaluation. In this example, if f1 and f2 had both written the numbers 1 or 2 respectively to a global variable, that global variable would have the value 2 in the end if the compiler evalutes left-to-right, but 1 if it evaluates right-to-left. Such code will work perfectly on one compiler, but crash miserably on another.

Comment: A compiler isn't required to evaluate the expression left to right or right to left.  It can interleaf different parts of the evaluation. The order the functions are called, for example, could depend on the complexity of the function arguments.  (This was a common strategy in the past.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, that is correct, I tried to keep the answer simple. In practice, all compilers will evaluate _expressions_ consistently either from left-to-right or right-to-left, because they create an internal binary tree structure out of the expression. That tree will be evaluated either with the left-most leaf first or the right-most leaf first, consistently. The order of a function's _parameter evaluation_ is a different beast, as it depends on calling convention and could vary depending on the number and type of the parameters etc. It is still a common strategy, in small 8/16 bit MCUs.

Comment: No! Compilers won't usually evaluate consistently either from left to right or from right to left.  One typical code generation technique is to estimate how many registers are needed for each branch (at each node), and always generate the code for the node which needs the most registers first.