# What is the flow of execution of a C++ code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int a=5; 
using namespace std;
int fun()
{
    a=17;
    return 3;
}
int main()
{
    a=a+fun();
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

What will be the flow when the execution begins? 
I have read that code execution begins at main. If this is the case the answer must be 8. But on the execution of this code in a c++ compiler answer is 20.

Comment: The order of evaluation of subexpressions of an expression is unspecified. In particular, in `a+fun()`, it's unspecified whether the value of `a` is taken before or after `fun()` is called (and a call to `fun()` changes the value of `a`, it being a global variable). Your compiler happens to choose to call `fun()` first.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818099/order-of-function-calling for more details.

Answer (score 1):

While interpreting the expression `a + fun()` a compiler may choose either to fetch the `a` value **before** executing the `fun()` invocation or **after** it. As a result the value fetched from `a` can be either the initial value of `5` or `13` assigned inside `fun()`, hence you get either `5+3` or `17+3`. Each of them is allowed.